# Find the points where a plot changes slope

Tags: python

I'm analyzing data that, once fitted with a cube root function, produces a plot similar to what is pictured below.

[image]

With this, I'd like to find the two points where the slope of the plot drastically changes - marked with the red circles. I've tried finding the second derivative, which I'd expect to return an array composed of 0's and 1's, but instead I get an array of float values that don't really tell me much.

Anyways, the inputs I'm using are 2 numpy arrays, and the function is of the form f(x) = a * (b * x ** 1/3 + c) + d

How would I go about finding these 2 points?, and would I be able to apply the same technique to a scenario with the reverse of this plot?

Comment: Second derivative should change from negative values to close to zero (between those two pints) and then to positive values. You can select those points in which the second derivative is arrives a close to zero value and when it starts to be positive (or over some threshold over zero).

Comment: @jibmdm I'm ashamed I didn't realize that....thanks for your help though!

Comment: If the comment was useful, you can mark it up.